# How to determine Euler angles of ZYZ rotations?

Tags: trigonometry, rotations, angle

Consider a point $\mathbf{P}=(x \ y \ z)^\text{T}$ which is transformed into $\mathbf{P'}=(x' \ y' \ z')^\text{T}$ in counterclockwise direction according to the *ZYZ* convention as follows:

$\begin{pmatrix} 
c_\alpha c_\beta c_\gamma -s_\alpha s_\gamma & -c_\alpha c_\beta s_\gamma - s_\alpha c_\gamma & c_\alpha s_\beta \\ 
s_\alpha c_\beta c_\gamma +c_\alpha s_\gamma & -s_\alpha c_\beta s_\gamma + c_\alpha c_\gamma & s_\alpha s_\beta \\ 
-s_\beta c_\gamma & s_\beta s_\gamma & c_\beta  
\end{pmatrix} $
$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\\ z\\ \end{pmatrix} = $
$\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y'\\ z'\\ \end{pmatrix}$,

where $\alpha, \gamma \in [0,2\pi)$, $\beta \in [0,\pi)$ together with $c_\phi=\cos(\phi)$, $s_\phi=\sin(\phi)$, and $\phi \in \{ \alpha, \beta, \gamma \}$. Is there any chance to express the triple of angles $(\alpha,\beta, \gamma)$ as a function of $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{P'}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

$$\tan\alpha=\frac{s_\alpha s_\beta}{c_\alpha s_\beta},$$

$$\tan\beta=\frac{\sqrt{(c_\alpha s_\beta)^2+(s_\alpha s_\beta)^2}}{c_\beta}=\frac{\sqrt{(s_\beta c_\gamma)^2+(s_\beta s_\gamma)^2}}{c_\beta},$$

$$\tan\gamma=\frac{s_\beta s_\gamma}{s_\beta c_\gamma}.$$

There is a degenerate case, when $s_\beta=0$. Then the matrix simplifies and you can adapt the formula. But you will notice that the angles are no more uniquely defined.

Comment: Thank you! If I understand correctly, you formalism is built upon the entries of the  coefficient matrix. Could you please help me how to obtain such matrix from $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{P'}$?

Comment: No, this is not possible, you need more points.

Comment: Actually, I have two sets, $\{(x_i \ y_i \ z_i): 1 \le i \le n \}$ and $\{(x'_i \ y'_i \ z'_i): 1 \le i \le n\}$, containing the original and transformed points, respectively. In this case, how can we produce this matrix? What is the restriction to the number of points, $n$?

Comment: @TobiR: pack three non-coplanar points in a matrix, say $\mathbf{Q}$, and solve $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{Q'}$ for $\mathbf{R}$. You can also use all $n$ points and solve by least-squares.

Comment: And what is the situation when all the *n* points lay in the same plane? If I take two non-parallel vectors, $\mathbf{P}_1=(x_1 \ y_1 \ z_1)^\text{T}$ and $\mathbf{P}_2=(x_2 \ y_2 \ z_2)^\text{T}$, and their cross product, $\mathbf{P}_3=\mathbf{P}_1×\mathbf{P}_2$, then is it true that the transformed form of $\mathbf{P}_3$ will be $\mathbf{P'}_3=\mathbf{P'}_1×\mathbf{P}_2'$, where $\mathbf{P'}_1$ and $\mathbf{P'}_2$ are the transformed forms of $\mathbf{P'}_1$ and $\mathbf{P'}_2$, respectively?

Comment: @TobiR In fact, three points is too much, you could do with just "one and a half" as you have three unknown parameters and every point gives two equations (not three because the norm is implicity preserved). But the computation is nonlinear and more difficult.

Comment: If I understand correctly, our two equations for $\mathbf{R}$ are as follows: $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{P'}$, $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{R}^\text{T}\mathbf{P'}$ using an arbitrary point, $\mathbf{P}$, and its transformed form, $\mathbf{P'}$. What condition will provide the equation for the three unknowns?

Comment: @TobiR: no, you wrote twice the same equation. All you need is in my answer and comments.

Comment: I understand what you wrote. However, what I only have are the $n$ points and their transformed forms. These $n$ points correspond to coordinates of a molecule in the 3D space. That is all what I know. If my molecule is linear, then all the points are in the same line and if this molecule is planar, then all the points are in the same plane. I cannot generate more points, unless by forming cross products... All in all, I do not know what is the situation in the co-planar and co-linear cases. Do you have any idea for these cases?

Comment: @TobiR: in the coplanar case, take the cross product. In the colinear case, one angle is undeterminate, set it to zero.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Does it matter which angle should be set to zero? E.g., if all the points lay on the *z* axis...